Filter empty string on Nest and .NET Core
I am trying to filter out empty string fields on my db
when i try query = e => e.Bool(b => b.Must(m => m.Term(m => m.Field(field).CaseInsensitive(true).Value("123"))));
its gives me the record where field value is 123.
my db also contains lists that has empty field values.
so when I run this
query = e => e.Bool(b => b.Must(m => m.Term(m => m.Field(field).CaseInsensitive(true).Value(""))));
the query is not being generated
I get all records both empty and non empty field records
I also tried using this
query = m => m.Wildcard(m => m.Verbatim().Field(field).CaseInsensitive(true).Value(""));
using verbatim generated the query like
{"bool":{"must":[{"wildcard":{"my_custom_field":{"value":"","case_insensitive":true}}}]}}]}}
but I didnt get any data at all.
when i see the actual db, the field is stored as my_custom_field: ""
